# How to count nodes in forest?

Tags: forest, count

I'm complete beginner in LaTeX, this is my first document.

I need to count every node in Forest, and nodes that are different color and I can't figure out how aggregate function .count works.

This is code, and the picture shows what I want.[image: automatic count of nodes]

The real Forest have more then 100 nodes, so I need to have automatic counting.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest,array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
         if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
  },
  grow'=0,
  draw,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge,
  rounded corners=2pt
  }
[a
  [b
        [c
                [D, draw=green]     
        ]  
  ]
  [1]
  [2
        [3, tikz={\node [draw=red,inner sep=1,fit to=tree,
label=right:\emph{selection}] {};}
                [4]
                [5, draw=green]     
        ]  
  ]
  [6]
  [7, tikz={\node [draw=red,inner sep=+1,fit to=tree,
label=right:\emph{selection}] {};}, draw=green]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest,array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


% count forest nodes
\newcounter{forestnodes}
\tikzset{
  count forest node/.code={\stepcounter{forestnodes}},
  reset forest nodes counter/.code={\setcounter{forestnodes}{0}},
}

% count green forest nodes
\newcounter{forestgreennodes}
\tikzset{
  count green forest node/.code={\stepcounter{forestgreennodes}},
  reset green forest nodes counter/.code={\setcounter{forestgreennodes}{0}},
  green node/.style={draw=green, count green forest node},
}



\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
      align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
    },
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    l sep=10mm,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    edge,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    /tikz/reset forest nodes counter,
    /tikz/reset green forest nodes counter,
    node options={count forest node},
  }
  [a
  [b
  [c
  [D, green node]     
  ]  
  ]
  [1]
  [2
  [3, tikz={\node [draw=red,inner sep=1,fit to=tree,
    label=right:\emph{selection}] {};}
  [4]
  [5, green node]     
  ]  
  ]
  [6]
  [7, tikz={\node [draw=red,inner sep=+1,fit to=tree,
    label=right:\emph{selection}] {};}, green node]
  ]
\end{forest}

\arabic{forestnodes}
\arabic{forestgreennodes}
\end{document}
```